# Write a query to calculate the total value of each product ordered. Columns: ProductName, TotalAmountOrdered

Tags: mysql, sql

```
# Product table contains 2 columns - id, name


create table Product
(id INT
,name varchar(100)
);
insert into Product(id, name) values
(1, 'Pen'),
(2, 'Paper'),
(3, 'Printer'),
(4, 'Sharpner'),
(5, 'Eraser'),
(6, 'Clip');
```

OrderInfo table contains 4 columns - id, customer_id, product_id, amount
customer_id is foreignkey to table Customer
product_id is foreignkey to table Product
amount is the value of order placed by a customer for a particular product

```
create table OrderInfo
(id INT
, customer_id INT
, product_id INT
, amount decimal);

insert into OrderInfo(id, customer_id, product_id, amount) values
(1, 3, 4, 565),
(2, 5, 4, 346),
(3, 1, 1, 365),
(4, 6, 3, 765),
(5, 1, 4, 245),
(6, 6, 2, 876);
```

The output should look like this

```
name amount
Pen 365
Paper 876
Printer 765
Shapner 1156
```

Comment: From table OrderInfo through foreign key product_id need to find the total amount of each foreign key.

Comment: Bro please help me

Comment: And note that your model only allows customers to order one type of product.

Comment: If you could help me here is the link 
https://1drv.ms/x/s!Aq88VBcAyQe2jHoesnLzyBO4UOfb?e=MXDbFq

there are few question if you could please solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast and easy to understand. Just join the two tables by the id of the product and group by the product. The result cann be summarized with `SUM()`

```
Select 
P.name
, SUM(O.amount)
FROM Product P
Inner Join OrderInfo O on O.product_id = P.id
Group by P.name
```